# Python not connecting to mongodb in docker container

Tags: docker, python

I have a simple python script which fetches certain values from the mongodb database. The script works fine on my local machine(host machine) but when i containarized my aplication it doesnt work. Here is my docker file.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
COPY mysript.py .
RUN pip3 install pymongo
CMD [ "python3", "myscript.py"]
```

My python code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://userName:password@localhost/sampledb")
db = client.sampledb
tutorial1 = {"title": "Working With JSON Data in Python","author": "Lucas"}
tutorial = db.sampledb
result = tutorial.insert_one(tutorial1)

for doc in tutorial.find():
  print(doc)
```

This code works fine on my local machine but not on the container. However i get an error like

`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 192.168.1.12:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 61b38be61c25e1ffbb4b9b0f, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('192.168.1.12', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('192.168.1.12:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>`

I have tried allowing by docker container IP by ufw firewall since its a connection refused issue but it doesnt work. I have also tried by changing the `localhost` field from the python code to docker container ip but that also doesnt helped me.

Does someone has any insights on this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How is your setup, 2 docker containers in the same VM ? different VMS? mongo somewhere else, like mongo atlas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using dockerized Mongodb like this?

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

you must replace localhost in this line of code with mongodb container name:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://userName:password@<mongodb cointaner name or ip>/sampledb")
```